# floating div that stays on top of page while going through page in React

Tags: html, reactjs

I created a long react based web page and I am thinking about placing a floating < div > where I will place hyperlinks to visit different parts of this page. While visiting the page, I need this floating < div > to always be visible. I will use this < div > within the return call of a react component that displays my whole page. Is this possible? how? My mind tells me to create states for the coordinates of the floating < div > but I don't understand how to update its position while browsing the page or selecting a link in that < div > that will take me to another part of the page so I can keep this < div > visible.

Comment: Sounds like a job for CSS. `position: fixed` will keep it in the exact same place, relative to the browser window

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is should be handled in [css](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_position&preval=fixed) using `position:fixed` than handling using Reactjs/js.

Comment: I used  < div id='linksToVisitPage' style={{position: 'fixed', top: '0px', right: '0px', width: '300px', border: '3px solid #73AD21', backgroundColor: 'white'}}  >  with react styling and all works well!